# ASP.NET C# GridView.ShowHeader and other properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid

I am using an ASP.NET GridView control, created dynamically with C# on a SharePoint web part. I am having some troubles setting the properties. Specifically, the ShowHeader property seems to be completely ignored, and it is set like so:

```
gv.ShowHeader = false;
```

This seems to work fine with the System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid, which I had previously used. I'm also having this issue with many of the other properties, such as BorderColor, BorderWidth, etc. However, CellPadding and CellSpacing work just fine when set similarly:

```
gv.CellPadding = 2;
gv.CellSpacing = 2;
```

I don't understand where the problem is. Here is the DataGrid code I had been using, which worked fine:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Specs");
DataSet flipped_ds = FlipDataSet(ds);
DataView dv = flipped_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
DataGrid outputGrid = new DataGrid();
outputGrid.DataSource = dv;
outputGrid.DataBind();
outputGrid.ShowHeader = false;
Controls.Add(outputGrid);
```

Here is the code that I have replaced this with for my GridView:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Bobst Specs");
DataSet flipped_ds = FlipDataSet(ds);
DataView dv = flipped_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = dv;
gv.DataBind();
gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
gv.CellPadding = 2;
gv.CellSpacing = 2;
gv.ShowHeader = false;
Controls.Add(gv);
```

Thanks for any help that I can get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried setting the gv properties first and then binding?

Comment: Yes, I tried setting all of those before the binding statements, and the results were the same.

Comment: After playing around for a while, I went back and tried setting the properties before binding again, and they worked! I don't know what I did wrong the first time, but it's working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

3 possible solutions
--Try disable `AutoGeneratedColumns`

```
                gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

--Try add the control to the page first before setting any property

Or
--Try a datatable instead and see if it works

```
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
                da.SelectCommand = cmd; 
                DataTable dt= new DataTable();
                dt.TableName = "Data";
                da.Fill(dt); 
                GridView gv = new GridView(); 
                gv.DataSource = dt; 
                gv.DataBind(); 
                gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true; 
                gv.CellPadding = 2; 
                gv.CellSpacing = 2; 
                gv.ShowHeader = false; 
                Controls.Add(gv);
```